# Puzzle: They're Coming. Help Me

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story

They’re going to kill me. I don’t know what they want from me. Goodness, I can’t remember what happened… The last memory I had was of two evil looking creatures peering in at the end of my English class… the next thought I had was of waking up dazed in this room lying under my old desk… Anyway, the room looks somewhat familiar…

> [image: ClassroomDiagram]

I can hear them coming back… what do I do before they get me…

### **What do I do?**

**Cryptic Hint #1**

> A long snake, twisting itself into strange shapes and awkward places, going down and back up, back down and back up, back down and back up… I saw it just before I passed out… It must have coiled around itself almost ten times!

**Cryptic Hint #2:**

> I remember my first day at school now… I don’t know if it’ll help, but when we got into the classroom the teacher made us all sit in a backwards “S” starting at the back of the classroom and working our way to the front… She was the last person to sit down. Don’t know if it helps though… Please help me!

**Cryptic Hint #3:**

> If you’ve attempted any of my other puzzles, you might want to consider applying those techniques here!

Comment: Is the photo supposed to represent the layout of the room?

Comment: @Areeb Yes it does. Sorry I didn't make it clearer.

Comment: The right side of the room has a strange wall... something hidden there?

Comment: @boboquack nothing special about the walls. Focus on the grey sections. Is there anything important about the spacing?

Comment: 13=26/2=1/2 the letters in the English alphabet...

Comment: By the way, NextTime wait a bit before giving hints. You want to let the people in other countries have a chance!

Comment: Mhm I keep forgetting that, sorry! I've been told twice now, I'm pretty forgetful :(

Comment: Please clarify Cryptic Hint 2:  Is it "working out way to the front" or "working our way to the front"?

Comment: Clarified. It is "working our way". Sorry!

Comment: Is boboquack's comment about 13 = 26/2 relevant?

Comment: @Donnelle Depends! Probably isn't if you ask me. But then again, it wouldn't be much fun if I were to partially solve the puzzle, were it?

Comment: Any more hints?

Comment: How about now?  :P

Comment: Sorry! I've been relatively inactive for such a long time... Let me add one more missing tag and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: ["Edited to remove the edit note about the edit."](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/49273/8) <-- best edit summary ever!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick!   (three weeks later):

> G e t   o u t   o f   t h E r **e**
>    (!)

Why take this action?
 
The reason begins with the classroom, a
9 ×7 grid with **63** rectangles.

[image]

Squeeze it, stretch it, and turn it.

> [image]

Now heed
[Donnelle’s
 astute observations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49372/18129),
that your dream-like paragraph...

> ...also contains **63** words,
>  which can form a matching grid that may be overlaid by the picture,
>  and that only the first letter of each word might be pertinent.

Here is how the seating stacks up
and how a walk about the classroom snakes around to the answer.

> ```
>                                            START AT THE BACK CORNER OF THE CLASSROOM
>                                                                  '.
>                             .''''''''''''''''''''''.               '.
>      They're      going     :   to         kill    :   me.         I '.         don't
>                             :                      :                   '.
>                             :    ______            :    ______           '.     ________
>      know         what      '. t|hey   |   want    '. f|rom   |   me.      '. G|oodness,|
>                            .'   |______|          .'   |______|           .'   |________|
>                            :                      :                       :
>      I            can't    :    remember   what   :    happened…  The     :    last
>                            :                      :                       :
>                            :     ______           :     ______            :     ________
>      memory       I         '. h|ad    |   was     '. o|f     |   two      '. e|vil     |
>                            .'   |______|          .'   |______|           .'   |________|
>       __________           :                      :                       :
>  ?  l|ooking    | creatures:    peering    in     :    at         the     :    end
>  '.(e|nigmatic?)|          :                      :                       :
>  :   |__________|          :     ______           :     ______            :     ________
>  :   of           my        '. E|nglish|   class…  '. t|he    |   next     '. t|hought  |
>  :                         .'   |______|          .'   |______|           .'   |________|
>  :                         :                      :                       :
>  :   I            had      :    was        of     :    waking     up      :    dazed
>  :                         :                      :                       :
>  :                         :     ______           :     ______            :     ________
>  :   in           this      '. r|oom   |   lying   '. u|nder  |   my       '. o|ld      |
>  :                          :   |______|           :   |______|            :   |________|
>  :                          :                      :                       :
>  :   desk…        Anyway,   :   the        room    :   looks      somewhat :   familiar…
>  '..........................'                      '.......................'
> ```
>
> (This interpretation allows for interpreting
>   “evil **looking** creatures” as
>   [repressed/recovered-memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repressed_memory)
>   [Freudian
>     symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(Freudian_dream_analysis))
>   that represent “evil **enigmatic** creatures.”)

**Behind the chalkboard – how this shook out**

The story paragraph most directly...

> ...matches the picture when arranged into a 9 ×7 word grid
>  (not 7× 9 as above).
>
> ```
>  They're   going   to        kill    me.       I       don't   know     what
>
>  they      want    from      me.     Goodness, I       can't   remember what
>
>  happened… The     last      memory  I         had     was     of       two
>
>  evil      looking creatures peering in        at      the     end      of
>
>  my        English class…    the     next      thought I       had      was
>
>  of        waking  up        dazed   in        this    room    lying    under
>
>  my        old     desk…     Anyway, the       room    looks   somewhat familiar…
> ```

So there are two arrangements to try out,
beginning by connecting vowels to possible word fragments.

> ```
>  9 x 7 layout:                   7 x 9 layout:     T   g   t   k   m   I   d
>
>                                                    k   w   t   w   f   m   G
>                                                    :                       :
>  T   g   t   k   m - I - d   k   w                 I   c   r   w   h   T   l
>                                                    :                       :
>  t   w   f   m   G   I   c   r   w                 m   I   h   w   o   t   e
>  :                                                                         :
>  h   T   l   m   I   h   w - o - t                 l   c   p - i - a - t - e
>  :                               :                 :       :               :
>  e   l   c   p   i - a - t - e   o                 o - m   E   c   t   n   t
>  :   :           :           :   :                         :   :
>  m   E   c   t   n   t   I   h   w                 I - h   w - o - w   u   d
>  :   :           :                                             :           :
>  o   w   u   d   i   t   r   l   u                 i - t   r   l   u   m   o
>  :               :
>  m   o   d - A - t   r   l   s   f                 d - A - t   r   l   s   f
> ```

Not many likely trails, though, and
a scarcity of vowels in the top left quadrants is unpromising.
 
So let’s try the 4 different ways to...

> ...overlay the picture, like a seating chart.
>
> ```
>                                                    T   g   t   k   m   I   d
>
>  T   g   t   k  [m]  I   d   k   w                [k]  w  [t]  w  [f]  m   G
>
>  t   w   f   m   G   I   c   r   w                 I   c   r   w   h   T   l
>
>  h  [T]  l  [m]  I  [h]  w  [o]  t                [m]  I  [h]  w  [o]  t   e
>
>  e   l   c   p   i   a   t   e   o                 l   c   p   i   a   t  [e]
>
>  m  [E]  c  [t]  n  [t]  I  [h]  w                [o]  m  [E]  c  [t]  n   t
>
>  o   w   u   d   i   t   r   l   u                 I   h   w   o   w   u   d
>
>  m  [o]  d  [A]  t  [r]  l  [s]  f                [i]  t  [r]  l  [u]  m   o
>
>                                                    d   A   t   r   l   s   f
>
>
>
>                                                    T   g   t   k   m   I   d
>                                                              .....
>  T  [g]  t  [k]  m  [I]  d  [k]  w                 k   w  [t]  w  [f]  m  [G]
>                                                          :       :           :
>  t   w   f   m   G   I   c   r   w                 I   c : r   w : h   T   l :
>                                                          :       :           :
>  h  [T]  l  [m]  I  [h]  w  [o]  t                 m   I  [h]  w  [o]  t  [e]
>                                                          :       :           :
>  e   l   c   p   i   a   t   e   o                [l]  c : p   i : a   t   e :
>                                                          :       :           :
>  m  [E]  c  [t]  n  [t]  I  [h]  w                 o   m  [E]  c  [t]  n  [t]
>                                                          :       :           :
>  o   w   u   d   i   t   r   l   u                 I   h : w   o : w   u   d :
>                                                          :       :           :
>  m   o   d   A  [t]  r   l   s   f                 i   t  [r]  l  [u]  m  [o]
>                                                                      '''''
>                                                    d   A   t   r   l   s   f
> ```

And there’s the answer, alright, in the fourth and final case.

Comment: Wonderful! I was starting to despair that no-one would be able to solve this puzzle, but humn has finally done it!

Comment: I really enjoyed walking around the classroom, @NextTimeDW, and will write up more about where else I wandered along the way

Comment: Looking forward to what you have to discover @humn!

Answer (score 5):

What do we have to work with?

We have a picture that:

> We could use as a mask. It's 9x7 = 63.

We have the introductory text, and two original cryptic hints.

> The introductory text is, conveniently, 63 words long.  If we take the first letter of each word, we get:
>    [image]

Then we can:

> Apply the mask to the grid.
>  [image]

Cryptic hint #2 suggests that:

> Once we have applied the mask to whatever, that we read it left-to-right, right-to-left, left-to-right.
>  [image]

And then something magic happens which has to do with a snake.  :P  I suspect we need to Vigenère decipher something from the text, following a path that either goes up-and-down, or coiling around, but I haven't been able to brute force it.

Comment: Reading your reasoning about relating the introductory text to the diagram, I'd say you are definitely on the right track. Sadly I'm at school at the moment, so the photos aren't loading, so I can't judge progress until I get back home sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for figuring out the most clever first steps, Donnelle! This led to the eventually accepted solution. A bounty of acknowledgement and appreciation is on its way and should arrive in about a week.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely guess

> Just shoot them!
>  Seeing the image and reading the puzzle made me think of space invaders.
>  - evil looking creatures(aliens).
>  - peering in at the end of the class(they are at the edge of the room)
>  - they are coming!
>  - the snake hint might suggest their trajectory.
>  - the image of the room looks like the initial display of the game.

Comment: I thought it could be a level of snake (the game).

Comment: @KaranAtree yeah, the hint made me think of the snake game too. But could not connect it to the puzzle :/

Comment: Good try! However it is quite unlikely that shooting the aliens would do anything to stop them, unfortunately. Do try again!